# Interface conversion when func() is on a custom struct type

Tags: go, interface, type-conversion

I have this code that works perfectly:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var funcMap = map[string]interface{}{
    "hello": hello,
}

func main() {
    callDynamically("hello")
}

func callDynamically(name string) {
    funcMap[name].(func())()
}

func hello() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

but my brain goes nuts if I try to define `hello()` on my struct type like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myType struct {
    field1  string
    field2  string
    funcMap map[string]interface{}
}

func main() {
    mt := &myType{
        field1: "qwe",
        field2: "asd",
        funcMap: map[string]interface{}{
            "hello": (*myType).hello,
        },
    }

    mt.callDynamically("hello")
}

func (mt *myType) callDynamically(name string) {
    mt.funcMap[name].(func())()
}

func (mt *myType) hello() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pPvmaL22_Td

I got this error:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is func(*main.myType), not func()
```

I really can't understand how to call a `func()` in `callDynamically` when the my function is defined on a custom struct type.

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add functions of `struct` instance to `funcMap` after `struct` initialization:

```
func main() {
    mt := &myType{
        field1: "qwe",
        field2: "asd",
        funcMap: map[string]interface{}{},
    }
    mt.funcMap["hello"] = mt.hello

    mt.callDynamically("hello")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A method in Go is just a function with some added syntactical sugar. The receiver is actually the first argument to the function, hence `(*myType).hello` - the method from the type - is really a `func(*myType)`; it does not have an instance of the receiver to call against, so it cannot be called without providing one explicitly as a function argument. This is covered [in the spec on Method Expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions).

If you instead took a method from an *instance* of the type, that argument would be populated already, so:

```
foo := &myType{}
fn := foo.hello
```

Here `fn` is a `func()` because it already has an instance to use as receiver. This is covered [in the spec on Method Values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values).